# How do I open a modal from a controller using Angular-materialize

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, materialize

I am using Materialize CSS and the Angular-materialize directives:

http://materializecss.com/modals.html

http://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/#modals

I am trying to do the following

1. User clicks button
2. Controller action gets fired and we go get data from an api
3. Modal is displayed to user and data returned is displayed

I have the following button

```
<a href="#MyModal" modal class="my-modal-trigger waves-effect waves-green btn right"Show Data/a>
```

and modal

```
<div id="MyModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row left">
                <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
                    <div class="card-content white-text">
                        <span class="card-title">Data</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <ul class="collection">
                            //loop the data
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a  class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn">Close</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and i have the following in my JS

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ['ngRoute', 'ui.materialize']);
```

How can i call a controller method to pop up the modal and fill it with data, from my controller

```
app.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $location, $http, AppConfig) {

    var params = { some stuff}

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: myURL,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        params: params
    })
        .success(function (data) {
            //pop up the modal and show the data
            Materialize.toast('Awesome, we got the data', 4000);
        })
        .error(function (status) {
            Materialize.toast('Bad stuff happened', 4000);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular-materialize lets you set an option `open` in your trigger. Use it to specify a variable that, when true, will launch your modal. Set it to false initially in your controller.

Use `ng-click` to call a function in your controller that fetches data from your API then sets the `open` variable to true on success.

Trigger:

```
<a href="#MyModal" class="btn" modal open="openModal" 
    ng-click="getDataOpenModal()">Show Data</a>
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.openModal = false;
$scope.getDataOpenModal = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/myUrl',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        params: params
    })
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
        $scope.openModal = true;
        Materialize.toast('Awesome, we got the data', 4000);
    })
    .error(function(status) {
        Materialize.toast('Bad stuff happened', 4000);
    });
}
```

EDIT: There are two other options you can set in your trigger, `ready` and `complete`

HTML

```
<a href="#MyModal" class="btn" modal open="openModal"
    ready="readyCallback()" complete="completeCallback()"
    ng-click="getDataOpenModal()">Show Data</a>
```

JS

```
$scope.readyCallback = function() {
    Materialize.toast("Modal ready", 4000);
}
$scope.completeCallback = function() {
    Materialize.toast("Modal complete", 4000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me with `$scope.$apply()` after `$scope.openModal = true;`

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting with this too, but no solution worked for me. I had to change html side.

**My html:**

```
<a href="" data-target='log_detail' modal ng-click="get_info_log()"><i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i></a>
```

**In controller:**

```
$scope.openModal = false
$scope.get_info_log = function(){  

    $scope.openModal = true;

}
```

**Data-target should match your modal id:**

```
!-- Modal Structure-->
<div id="log_detail" class="modal modal-fixed-footer setup-modal">
        <div class="modal-content">                  
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-light btn">Close</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```